# Javascript sort table div by time date

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table like this

```html
<div class="wrapper-3OdqYJdx">
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>1:59:08 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">David</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:10:00 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Vonn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:40:02 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Anna</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>3:02:01 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How I can sort this table by time date, only with javascript, without using jquery, newest on top?

I read about sorting by number here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table_number

But I dont know how to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: I would suggest you to keep the data in an JS array in memory and render the array's content into HTML. You can sort the JS array, then re-render the HTML from the JS array. This should make it much more easy.

Comment: You have not tried out anything to sort the table.. The logic should be, pick each row, select the date from the div with class `cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45` Convert that to date text. Sort it. Please start to implement the logic and ask if you need any support on implementing the logic, rather that asking the whole thing in a single question.

Comment: Also, how is the table being generated? I'd recommend storing the unix timestamp (a number), and then sorting based on that. You shouldn't be parsing dates from a string (or at least avoid that as much as possible).

Comment: @Terry I have no control on the generated table. I have only the result displayed on my screen. I would want to use a browser extension to add the javascript to the current HTML to modify it + hide what I dont need + highlight with red color what I want to focus

Comment: Also w3schools is not a great resource

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sort on date and time

I assume the classnames are static. If dynamic we need more code

I also added some CSS for visualisation

The datestring of `1/11/2022 1:59:08 PM` is parsable without RegExp so I use it as is

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".wrapper-3OdqYJdx")
const getDateFromSpans = spans => new Date(`${spans[0].textContent} ${spans[1].textContent}`);

const rows = [...container.querySelectorAll(".bodyRow-OX45")]
  .sort((a,b)=> getDateFromSpans(a.querySelectorAll('.timeCell-OX45 span')) - getDateFromSpans(b.querySelectorAll('.timeCell-OX45 span')))
container.append(...rows)
```

```css
.bodyRow-OX45 { border: 1px solid black; }
span::after { content: " - " }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-3OdqYJdx">
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="ticker-OX45">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>1:59:08 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="ticker-OX45">David</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:10:00 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="ticker-OX45">Vonn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:40:02 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="ticker-OX45">Anna</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>3:02:01 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the `children` list of the container into an array of `[Date, Element]` pairs, sort by the first column, then convert the sorted array of `[Date, Element]` pairs back into an array of `Element`s. Finally, you just have to loop through the resulting array to append the child elements into the container one by one.

```js
var map = Array.prototype.map;
var mainEl = document.getElementById("main");
var childEls = map.call(mainEl.children, function (el) {
  var d = el.children[0].textContent;
  var t = el.children[1].textContent;
  return [Date.parse(d + " " + t), el];
}).sort(function (a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
}).map(function (pair) {
  return pair[1];
});
for (let childEl of childEls) {
  mainEl.appendChild(childEl);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div><span>1/11/2022</span> <span>1:59:08 PM</span>  David</div>
  <div><span>1/11/2022</span> <span>12:10:00 AM</span> Anna</div>
  <div><span>1/11/2022</span> <span>12:40:02 AM</span> John</div>
  <div><span>1/11/2022</span> <span>3:02:01 PM</span>  Vonn</div>
</div>
```

Just in case you don't know `map` or `call`:

```
> | [1, 2, 3].map(function (x) {
  |   return x + 1;
  | })
< | [2, 3, 4]
> | Array.prototype.map.call([1, 2, 3], function (x) {
  |   return x + 1;
  | })
< | [2, 3, 4]
```

The `map.call` pattern is required because `mainEl.children` has no `map` method (type `document.children.map` in the browser console and see what happens).

> **Side note**
>
> As suggested in the comments, in modern JS syntax you would write `childEls = [...mainEl.children].map(...)`, which boils down to the same result. However, I did a perf test a couple of years ago to compare stuffs like `map.call(mainEl.children, ...)` and `[...mainEl.children].map(...)`, and the modern syntax was far slower than the old one. Maybe things have changed since then, I let you check by yourself :-)

It's probably a good idea to write your own "parse" function, because you never know how the browser implementation of `Date.parse(...)` deals with non standard date formats. Just pick the various bits from `d + " " + t`, and make a `Date` object with `new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Answer (score 0):

Another variant on the above. Query all elements to find the `spans` containing the dates and generate a timestamp to use in the comparison. An array `sort` function can compare the values to sort the results as desired before regenerating the HTML.

```js
const d=document;
const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);

const parent=q('div.wrapper-3OdqYJdx');
const col=qa('div.timeCell-OX45');
const nodes=[];

col.forEach( div=>{
  let tmp={
    node:div.parentNode,
    time:new Date( [ ...qa('span', div ) ].map( span=>{
      return span.textContent;
    }).join(' ') ).getTime()
  };
  nodes.push( tmp )
});


nodes.sort( (a,b)=>{
  if( a.time > b.time )return 1;
  if( a.time < b.time )return -1
  if( a.time==b.time )return 0;
});

parent.innerHTML='';
nodes.forEach( obj=>parent.appendChild( obj.node ) );
```

```css
span{padding:0.25rem}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-3OdqYJdx">
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>1:59:08 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">David</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:10:00 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Vonn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:40:02 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Anna</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>3:02:01 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works too - I do not see the improvement over [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70664463/295783) though. This is shorter: 
`nodes.sort( (a,b) => a.time - b.time); 
nodes.forEach( obj=>parent.appendChild( obj.node ) );`

Comment: Indeed  -your answer is more concise! Always more than one way to skin a cat as they say

Answer (score 0):

Your classes in Dom may be generated dynamic, so this answer will help you:

```js
const times = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="timeCell"] span:first-child')

const data=[];

times.forEach( item => {
 data.push({
   time: new Date(item.innerText+" "+item.nextElementSibling.innerText ).getTime(),
   parent: item.parentElement.parentElement

 })
})


data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.time - b.time;
});

const newDom = document.querySelector('div[class*="wrapper"]');
data.forEach(item => newDom.append(item.parent));
```

```css
div[class*="timeCell"] span:first-child{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-3OdqYJdx">
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">John</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>1:59:08 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">David</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:10:00 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Vonn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>12:40:02 AM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyRow-OX45">
    <div class="cell-OX45 symbolCell-OX45">
      <div class="name-OX45">Anna</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 descriptionCell-OX45">paid</div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 timeCell-OX45"><span>1/11/2022</span><span>3:02:01 PM</span></div>
    <div class="cell-OX45 buttonsCell-OX45">
      <div title="Edit" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA"></div>
      <div title="Remove" role="button" class="button-mpsUn-6R apply-common-tooltip button-165AA dangerous-165AA"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```